# Anomalous baryon current in the Standard Model (SM) and the stability of free protons within the confines of the SM

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quantum-anomalies, proton-decay

In the Standard Model, the baryon number is not exactly conserved due to anomaly but the decay rate is extraordinarily small at ordinary temperatures. Does this make free protons unstable in the Standard model itself (with no new physics and no new particles)? If the free proton is really unstable, what would be its dominant mode of $B$-violating decay?

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/288892/standard-model-proton-decay-rate

Comment: The answer by Thomas, in the linked post above, points out that _"Electroweak instantons violate baryon number (and lepton number) by three units (all three generations participate in the 't Hooft vertex). As a result, the proton is absolutely stable in the standard model."_ I could not follow the consequence of proton stability in the SM (last sentence) from the reason given (first sentence).

Comment: The B violating transitions can only change B by 3. The proton state is B = 1, while the decay product state has B = 0 (since there are no lighter baryons that the proton could decay into). You can't go from 1 to 0 by adding or subtracting 3.

Comment: Here is a nice review of the [6-quark effective operator](https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.2640) flipping chirality. You add the leptons in the vertex, and tie the particles up with suitable  allowed EW interactions, to lead to a proton and suitable leptons.  The onus is on you, but the rate is unforgiving.